# How can I pad a Vector of Strings in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'd like to pad a vector of strings with a given value on all sides (i.e., top, bottom, right, left). For example, the following vector of strings:

```
1122
1122
3344
3344
```

should look like this:

```
000000
011220
011220
033440
033440
000000
```

Of course, this representation is purely for visual purposes and it is actually a Vector of strings.

I found I can accomplish this with the following code.

```
val v = Vector("1122", "1122", "3344", "3344")
Vector("000000") ++ (for { r <- v } yield "0" + r + "0") ++ Vector("000000")
```

However, I am fairly new to Scala and I feel I might be missing a better way to accomplish this. Is there a better way to pad a Vector of Strings in Scala with a given value?

Comment: `"000000" +: v.map("0"+_+"0") :+ "000000"`  This isn't the most general approach.  It's just a little more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jwvh's `map` approach with the `*` operator on `String`:

```
def repeat(len: Int, c: Char) = c.toString * len

def padLeftRight(s: String, len: Int, c: Char) = {
  repeat(len - 1 - s.size, c) + s + c
}

def padSeq[S <: Seq[String]](xs: S, c: Char) = {
  val len = xs.map(_.size).max + 2
  val padded = repeat(len, c)
  padded +: xs.map(padLeftRight(_, len, c)) :+ padded
}
```

Using `padSeq` with your example:

```
val v = Vector("1122", "1122", "3344", "3344")
val result = padSeq(v, '0')
```

gives:

```
Vector("000000", "011220", "011220", "033440", "033440", "000000")
```